# Nodejs server when using postgres as database in docker shows error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, deployment

I have nodejs for the api part. And the data is stored in the postgres database. But when I connect to the postgres, it shows the error.

```
(node:25) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.106.238.66:5432
    at /app/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:45:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:25) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:25) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.106.238.66:5432
    at /app/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:45:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '10.106.238.66',
  port: 5432
}
```

Code for server

```
const { Pool } = require("pg");
const pgClient = new Pool({
  user: keys.pgUser,
  host: keys.pgHost,
  database: keys.pgDatabase,
  password: keys.pgPassword,
  port: keys.pgPort,
  // user: "postgres",
  // host: "postgres",
  // database: "postgres",
  // password: "password",
  // port: 5432,
});

pgClient.connect();

pgClient.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("db connected");
});
```

The error persists with the docker images even though I have provided all the env variables.

```
version: "3"

services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
  redis:
    image: "redis:latest"
  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - api
      - client
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "3050:80"
  api: # Changed from server to api, as nginx has server as reserved keyword
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./server # The path is specified in the context while only the name is specified in the dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379 #From docs
      - PG_USER=postgres
      - PG_HOST=postgres
      - PG_DATABASE=postgres
      - PG_PASSWORD=password
      - PG_PORT=5432 #From docs
    restart: always
  client:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client #The path from where to pick the dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
    environment:
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
  worker:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./worker
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./worker:/app
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
```

The only ways to fix this was to restart the server i.e deleting the container and starting it again. But this seems more like a hack and not a solution. How do I fix this??

Comment: Where is pgHost coming from?

Comment: @jjanes

pgHost and all the other envs are coming from keys which takes in env variables. so pgHost = keys.pgHost & pgHost = process.env.PG_HOST

Comment: docker networks usually start with 172, not 10.  Do you know where 10.106.238.66 is coming from?

Comment: No idea @jjanes

Answer (score 0):

You are using **Promises** anywhere in your code, and they need to be handled properly.

This exception is because Promise is completed with **reject()**, or an exception is thrown which is not being handled.

Use **[try/catch](https://medium.com/@techno021/a-fix-to-the-unhandled-promise-rejection-warning-4fc0598896fe)** statements to handle the exception.

Comment: Lets suppose that's the case. But that doesn't solve my problem how to make server start or connect only after postgres has been downloaded and started